# Rotativa 1.6.4 / Wkhtmltopdf images not displaying (get blank image)

Tags: c#, .net, razor, model-view-controller, pdf-generation

I am currently creating MVC 5 web application, to generate internal document.

I have problem to create PDF file using Rotavia. When i create document, a get a black images (don't see image, see empty border).

Controller:

```
     public ActionResult GeneratePDF(int id = 0)
        {


            var documentToGenerate = repository.getDocumentWithAttachment(id);


return new ViewAsPdf("MainTemplate/documentPDFView", documentToGenerate)
                {
                    FileName = (documentToGenerate.documentNumber + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ".PDF"),
                    PageSize = Size.A4,
                    PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape,
                    IsBackgroundDisabled = false,
                    IsGrayScale = false,
                    IsJavaScriptDisabled = true
                };

        }
```

View part:

```
// for test reason add two actions...
    <img src="@Url.Action("getFileAttachment", "Attachment", new { id = 18 })" alt="@file.value.name" style="height: 150px; width: 200px;">
    <img src="http://localhost:921/Document/Attachment/getFileAttachment/18" alt="@file.value.name" style="height: 150px; width: 200px;">
```

Attachment/getFileAttachment/18 response FileResult (testing png and jpeg files, AllowAnonymous,  work fine...)

any hint to resolve issue / problem ? :)

Comment: Have you tried using ActionAsPdf instead of ViewAsPdf? Regarding the images, you can also try using the Server.MapPath() while creating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use, for example, `<img src="@Server.MapPath("relative_path_here")">`, because Rotativa get images, css styles, etc. as local resources.

Maybe you can try to use:

```
<img src="@Server.MapPath(Url.Action("getFileAttachment", "Attachment", new { id = 18 }))">
```